# Сортировка по двум tv полям pdoResources

Tags: modx

Имеется код:

```
[[pdoResources?
   &parents=`4`
   &depth=`2`
   &tpl=`item`
   &sortbyTV=`price`
   &sortbyTVType=`integer`
   &where=`{"template":4}`
   &includeTVs=`old_price,new,image,price,top,sold`
   &sortdir=`ASC`
]]
```

Как рассортировать результаты сначала по одному TV, затем по второму? Например, сначала идет сортировка по полю price, затем после нее идет сортировка по sold.

Answer (score 1):

Вы путаете с `getResources`, в `pdoResources` есть параметр `&sortby` в котором можно указывать JSON строку с массивом нескольких полей (включая ТВ параметр, если он указан в параметре `&includeTVs`):

```
&sortby=`{"price":"ASC", "sold":"DESC"}`
```